# Circular imports when creating database

Tags: python, flask

First time ever using Flask to create a web app., and I'm running into issues creating a database. I get the error:

`ImportError: cannot import 'app' from partially initialized module 'website' (most likely due to circular import).`  (In other words, I can't even run the application so that I can get to creating the database; my issue lies primarily in getting the app to run).

It's probably true that it's due to circular imports, but I've been following along with a tutorial, and mine doesn't seem to work, even after a full project reorganization. For curiosity, this is what it looks like now:

```
C:\...flaskProject
     static/
     templates/
          about-page.html
          blog-page.html
          home-page.html
          photography-page.html
     website/
          __init__.py
          modules.py
          routes.py
     app.py
```

The problem code likely lies in `app.py` and `__init__.py`, so, in that order:

```
from website import app

if __name__ == '__main__'
     app.run(debug=True)
```

and

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from website import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
# *!* app.config['SECRET_KEY'] =
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite///:database.db'
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I've been running the commands `python app.py`, `set FLASK_APP=app.py` -> `flask run`, and `set FLASK_APP=__init__.py` -> `flask run`. I've seen lots on here (and in python documentation) about circular imports, and it makes some sense to me. I just don't think it's happening here, but it very well could be without my knowing. I've also looked into the `static/` file that was included when I started this project in PyCharm once I selected Flask from the menu, but I believe that's irrelevant to me, for now.
Any ideas on the circular import claim? How I could fix it, and any information which would help me in this field in the future? Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that the file `app.py` contains `from website import app`?  That doesn't seem circular?  I think you should rename `app.py` to `main.py`, or something like that.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, that's all the code within app.py. I renamed it to run.py and it's still the same issue.

Comment: And what does `routes` import?

Comment: I think @TimRoberts is on the correct path here... if routes is importing app that'll be your circular import. Assuming that is true I would either put your routes in your app file or use Blueprints if you want to maintain separate files.

Comment: Ah, yes. There is an "from website import app" inside of routes.py. @BrettJ You'd recommend putting all the routes within my (now) run.py file? And, if not that, using Blueprints? I'm not familiar with Blueprints, but I'm sure I could look those up.

Comment: Also, that's strange. Assuming I'm not blind, it seems this is exactly what's done in the tutorial I'm watching. Can anyone fact check me and/or explain the difference between the tutorial and what I have? The link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr4QMBUPxWo. And in case that doesn't work, the title is "Flask Course - Web Application Development" by freeCodeCamp.org.

Comment: Update: I found a temporary solution, not sure if this will work long-term, but: Shifting the ```from website import routes``` below all the app.config's worked. Does this follow logically (in regards to circular import)? Because this was quite literally the only thing I changed; the ```...import app``` inside of routes.py is still there, since I use ```app.route(...)```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the circular import error because of partially initialized module app (circular imports). From the `app.py` when it calls `from website import app`, it initializes the website module i.e, the `__init__.py`. In `__init__.py`, the 3rd line `from website import routes` is causing the trouble. Your website module has not completed it's import and you are trying to import routes from this partially initialized module website.

The 3rd line in your `__init__.py` should be replaced by something like -

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from website.routes import route1, route2 # This is how it should be


app = Flask(__name__)
# *!* app.config['SECRET_KEY'] =
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite///:database.db'
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Now, it will not try to initialize the website module again. But, if you have `from website import app` in the `routes.py` file then I would suggest to move this import to the `app.py` file.

```py
from website import app
from website.routes import route1, route2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```